# CSS Triangle Under Link On Hover (WITHOUT UL/LI/SPAN)?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover, css-shapes

I am pulling my hair out trying to do what should be a very, very simple effect. Here's what I want this to look like :

[image: CSS triangle under link]

When you hover over a text link, I want a small orange triangle to appear under this line. All of the responses I have found use ul and li to make this work, but that is not how I have my code set up and will not work for what I'm doing.

```
<nav class="row mainnav">
    <div class="large-7 large-centered columns show-for-medium-up">
      <div class="small-3 columns">
        <a href="#">Work</a>
      </div>
      <div class="small-3 columns">
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </div>
      <div class="small-3 columns">
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </div>
      <div class="small-3 columns">
        <a href="#">Blog</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="row"><div class="large-9 large-centered columns show-for-medium-up rectangle">&nbsp;</div></div>
```

I'm building this site using foundation 4. Because I want my links set up a certain way and I want this white line under my links, I can't use the ul/li method to get the triangle hover, or even a really good `display: block;` method I found but wouldn't work for me at all. I figure if I duplicate this section under those two sections:

```
<nav class="row mainnav">
    <div class="large-7 large-centered columns show-for-medium-up">
      <div class="small-3 columns">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="small-3 columns">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="small-3 columns">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="small-3 columns">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

That this should work. This is the css I currently have.

```
.mainnav a {
font-family: "Quicksand", Verdana, sans-serif;
color: #8cc63f;
font-size: 1.75em;
}
.mainnav a:hover {
color: #c97932;
}
.arrow {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 10px solid transparent;
border-right: 10px solid transparent;
border-top: 10px solid #c97932;
margin: 25px auto;
display: none;
}
.mainnav a:hover + .arrow {
display: block;
}
```

Clearly the `display: block;` method can't work because these items aren't side by side. Please help with this! I already had to give up on the sliding js animation I wanted this to do because I couldn't figure it out... :( Thank you in advance!

**Allow me to clarify a bit with this line with the class of rectangle.**
This is all it is, but it has to go between the links and the area the triangle appears. This is why the ul/li method will not work.

```
.rectangle {
    height: 1.5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    // margin: 1% 0% 3% 0%;
}
```

**Working Fix for my Issue!**

HTML

```
  <nav class="row mainnav">
    <div class="large-7 large-centered columns show-for-medium-up">
      <div class="small-3 columns underline">
        <a href="#">Work</a>
      </div>
      <div class="small-3 columns underline">
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </div>
      <div class="small-3 columns underline">
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </div>
      <div class="small-3 columns underline">
        <a href="#">Blog</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

CSS

```
   .mainnav {
    height: 100px;
  }

  .mainnav a {
    font-family:"Quicksand", Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #8cc63f;
    font-size: 1.75em;
  }

  .mainnav a:hover {
    color: #c97932;
  }

  .mainnav a, .mainnav a:hover{ text-decoration:none;}
  .mainnav a:hover:after {
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    width:100%;
    height:0;
    text-align:center;
    content : "\25B2";
    color: @orange;
  }

  .underline {
    margin: 10px 0px; 
    padding: 5px 0px;    
    border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
    overflow:visible;
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably do want to use `display:block;`, however, you need to position the element so that it is below the line.

```
.mainnav a:hover + .arrow {
    display: block;
    position: relative; /* you could also try 'absolute' here */
    top: -50px; /* this will be how far down you want the triangle */
}
```

#### Edit:

I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/netinept/PEPH7/) to demonstrate. I had to add some CSS definitions so that the rest of it would show up like described.

For posterity, here are the relevant rules:

```
.mainnav a, .mainnav a:hover{ text-decoration:none;}
.mainnav a:hover:after {
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    content : "\25B2";

    color:yellow;
}

.columns {float : left; margin:10px;}
```

`content : "\25B2";` inserts the unicode ▲. This can be substituted of course with a `background-image: url(...)` or whatever you need it to be.

#### Edit 2:

See [this version of the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/netinept/PEPH7/2/). Instead of putting the border on the `a` (which caused a weird ever-expanding width issue), I put it on the `div` which wraps the `a` and added margin and padding to that `div`, then gave the "arrow" a `height: 0;` so that the box would not expand on `:hover`.

#### Here is the complete solution:

```css
.mainnav a {
    font-family:"Quicksand", Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #8cc63f;
    font-size: 1.75em;
}
.mainnav a:hover {
    color: #c97932;
}
.arrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #c97932;
    margin: 25px auto;
    display: none;
}
.mainnav a, .mainnav a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.mainnav a:hover:after {
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    top:5px;
    width:100%;
    height:0;
    text-align:center;
    content :"\25B2";
    color:#c97932;
}
.columns {
    float : left;
    margin:0;
    padding:5px 10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #f00;
    overflow:visible;
}
```

```html
<nav class="mainnav">
    <div>
        <div class="columns"><a href="#">Work</a></div>
        <div class="columns"><a href="#">About</a></div>
        <div class="columns"><a href="#">Contact</a></div>
        <div class="columns"><a href="#">Blog</a></div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! However, if I use that when I don't put the second row under the line, it just bumps the line down. If I do that with the second row there, nothing is showing up at all.

Comment: @JacquelynLaraeChastain I have updated the answer and created a JSFiddle with the solution.

Comment: Thank you again! However, this is the point I've gotten to already... this works really great, but I need to have that thin white line in between the link and the triangle, as shown in the picture I linked to. This is where my entire problem lies. My only other option would be to position the line absolutely, which I can't do: This site is responsive.

Comment: @JacquelynLaraeChastain you can use a `border-bottom` with some right and left padding on the `a` to get that effect.

Comment: Can you show me how I would go about doing that? You've been very helpful!

Comment: @Jackie I have edited the answer further to try to address this concern. Hopefully you can see the pattern and adapt it further to your needs.

Comment: Sweet! I got it to work. I'll show my fix in my top post. Couldn't have done it with you. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

please try this below code

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Nav</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
  <div class="mainnav">
    <div class="list-item"><a href="#">Work</a><div class="arrow"></div></div>
    <div class="list-item"><a href="#">About</a><div class="arrow"></div></div>
    <div class="list-item"><a href="#">Contact</a><div class="arrow"></div></div>
    <div class="list-item"><a href="#">Blog</a><div class="arrow"></div></div>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style>
.mainnav {
    font-family: "Quicksand", Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #8cc63f;
    font-size: 1.75em;
}

.mainnav > .list-item {
    display:inline-block;
}
.columns a:hover {
    color: #c97932;
}
.arrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #c97932;
    margin: 25px auto;
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    bottom:25px;
    display: none;
}
.mainnav .list-item a:hover + .arrow {
    display: block;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Vineesh, like I said in my post, I can't use the ul method with what I'm trying to do. I have tried this, it won't work with the line that I'm trying to put between the area the arrow appears and the link itself. I do appreciate your answer though.

Comment: I'm sorry, that isn't remotely close to what I explained or what's shown in the image. This also doesn't solve my issue with needing the line between it.